# Aggregate large raster to raster with lower resolution via mean (R)

Tags: r, mean, large-data, r-raster

I have a fairly large raster file with a resolution of 0.9 arcsec x 0.9 arcsec carrying values between 0 and 100 (and 255 for NA) called forest1. I want to aggregate this raster to the resolution of another raster (called dfr_2010_crop) which has a 0.5° x 0.5° resolution using the mean of values. Unfortunately, the strategy I am currently using requires too much memory. Namely, I am using

```
TreeCover = rasterToPoints(forest1, fun=NULL, spatial=T) 
TreeCoverPercent <- rasterize(TreeCover, dfr_2010_crop, fun=function(x,...) {sum(x, na.rm=T)/(4*10^4)}, field=g )
```

whereby g is the correct field I have saved before. 4*10^4 is the number of 0.9 arcsec x 0.9 arcsec in a 0.5° x 0.5° cell. R tells me that he cannot allocate a vector of the size of 7.9GB after running the first line. I have tried to solve this problem in the following ways:

```
rasterOptions(maxmemory=1e+08)
```

And, after this did not work I have tried to work in blocks. I tried following the approach given here ([https://strimas.com/post/processing-large-rasters-in-r/][1]) where they use the calc() function when working in blocks. However, I failed to customite it to my setting as I do not know how to call the blocks as raster files inside of the loop. However, here is my try:

```
canProcessInMemory(forest1, 1, TRUE)
#working in block
f_in <- f
f_out <- tempfile(fileext = ".tif")

# input and output rasters
r_in <- stack(f_in)
r_out <- raster(r_in)

# blocks
b <- blockSize(r_in)
print(b)

r_in <- readStart(r_in)
r_out <- writeStart(r_out, filename = f_out)

# loop over blocks
for (i in seq_along(b$row)) {
  # read values for block
  # format is a matrix with rows the cells values and columns the layers
  v <- getValues(r_in, row = b$row[i], nrows = b$nrows[i])
  
  # mean cell value across layers
  v <- rasterToPoints(v, fun=NULL, spatial=T)
  
  # write to output file
  r_out <- writeValues(r_out, v, b$row[i])
}

# close files
r_out <- writeStop(r_out)
r_in <- readStop(r_in)
```

Looking forward to any suggestions and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ratio of your resolutions turns out to be an exact integer:

```
res1 = 0.9/(60*60) # resolution converted to degrees
res2 = 0.5
res.factor = res2 / res1
res.factor
# [1] 2000
```

You can double check this with you actual rasters using `res.factor = res(forest1) / res(dfr_2010_crop)` - I can't do that because you did not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

This means that you can simply use raster::aggregate to change the resolution.

```
TreeCoverPercent = aggregate(forest1, res.factor)
```

In case your res.factor was not a precise integer, then you can still use this method by rounding to the nearest integer, followed by resampling to the final desired resolution.

```
TreeCoverPercent = aggregate(forest1, round(res.factor))
TreeCoverPercent = resample(TreeCoverPercent, dfr_2010_crop)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the reproducible example. I will keep that in mind for future questions! And yes, you are right, in my case, its an exact integer so your solution works perfectly.